# How do I set the Verbatim font (or the mono font) to bold by default?

Tags: fonts, formatting, fontspec, bold

I'm using the `fancyvrb` package and the `Verbatim` (with an uppercase V) environment. However, the font I'm using is to light for my taste, so I'd like to make it bold without having to write `\textbf{}` on every line.

My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
% preamble
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Ligatures={NoRequired,NoCommon,NoContextual},Numbers={Lining,Monospaced},Scale=0.8]{Courier New}
% more preamble
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
% final part of the preamble
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
this text is in a monospace font
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

I've tried adding something like `Uppercase=Bold,Lowercase=Bold,Numbers=Bold` to the `\setmonofont` options, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I've also tried using the command `\verbatimfont`, but that didn't work for me either.

Thnks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you tied to `fancyvrb` for other reasons than shown in your MWE?  For example, you make no use of `commandchars`, etc.

Comment: I use `Verbatim` for computer code. I want to be able to display normal code in black and comments in grey so the reader doesn't have to be familiar with the specific language's comment delimiters and can just differentiate code and comments without any extra effort. If there's another package that can do that in a simple way, I'm not tied to `fancyvrb`.

Comment: You need a bold mo,o font. `cm-unicode` and `Latin Modern` have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just load the `Courier New Bold` font as the mono font. I've removed your `Ligatures` and `Numbers` options since these aren't available in this font (they produce warnings.)

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
% preamble
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.8]{Courier New Bold}
% more preamble
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
% final part of eh preamble
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
this text is in a monospace font
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Well, this works and is trivial to implement. Thanks a lot. :) Just out of academic interest, will this work for any font that has a defined bold version? And if a font doesn't have a bold version then how can I enforce a `\textbf` equivalent?

Comment: Yes (same for italics, italic bold etc); basically any face that the font has. If a font doesn't have a bold face, then no, it won't work. It's possible (but not recommended) to use `FakeBold`. See the `fontspec` documentation for details.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 4):

An alternative version that loads the Black (or ExtraBold, etc.) weight as “bold”, and also sets up italics:

```
\setmonofont{Some Font}[
  Scale = MatchLowercase ,
  UprightFont = * Bold ,
  ItalicFont = * Bold Italic ,
  BoldFont = * Black ,
  BoldItalicFont = * Black Italic ]
```

Change this to match the names of your font files.  For example, if you have `Some Font-Bold.otf` and `Some Font-ExtraBold.otf` on your system, you would instead load `UprightFont = *-Bold`, `BoldFont = *-ExtraBold`, and `Extension = .otf`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try late tonight; I like the idea of having italics as well.